# how to generate a confusion matrix for single categorical predictor?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjMbk.png)
the student variable is categorical variable. I don't know how to do the Q3

I tried the following code

```
glm.1<-glm(default~student, data = Default, family = binomial)
summary(glm.1)
Default$prob<-fitted.values(glm.1)
summary(Default$prob)
Default$yes=ifelse(Default$prob>0.5,1,0)
table(Default$default,Default$yes)
```

but it only generate 1 column result